# Event refund - cancelling payment

Tags: civievent, payment, refund

I'm looking for some clarification before I proceed any further in event cancelling/refunds.

Here's the situation:

- Event was cancelled.
- I issued a refund via PayPal.
- I then recorded a manual refund in the contribution record, not realizing PayPal updates that automatically.
- (Unbeknownst to me at the time to me) PayPal automatically updated CiviEvent with the refund.
- The payment now has a balance as it was doubly refunded.
- There does not appear to be the means to delete a payment.

Is there an established process to rectify this? A means to delete a payment record? Should I just issue a payment for the balance to zero it out?

Any insight is appreciated.

Much thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This extension](https://github.com/pradpnayak/financialtrxncustomfields) provides the ability to delete payments. To enable the delete option

1. Install the extension
2. Enable to option under CiviCRM >> Administer >> CiviContribute >> CiviContribute Component Settings.

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: That's useful but we'd never know from the Readme!  Could you add a bit of explanation about what your extension provides into its README.md?

Comment: Thanka for the response Pradeep.  I'm hoping that will do the job, however I'm a bit hesitant to install extensions that aren't available in the extensions directory and don't have a good bit of history and activity I can follow as I'm unsure if they will be supported in future releases and what ramifications that might have.  I don't have experience or skill enough to evaluate the code.   I do appreciate the response though and I'm looking forward to seeing what your extension is capable of.  Is anyone aware of another method of deleting a payment?

Comment: I can move this extension into GitLab and can make it available under /extensions. For doing that I need to write documentation/create pages etc which is on my todo list. Right now we are busy with Civi updates. Some helps around documentation will be really helpful

Comment: I've not yet been involved in documentation specifically for this project, but have for others in the past on GitHub.  I'd be happy to lend a hand if it would be useful.  I'll try to better familiarize myself with the extension over the next few days.

Comment: I ended up testing and using this extension and it works very well.  Much thanks.  Is it ok to enable and disable the 'delete payment' at will once I've accomplished the payment deletions I need?

Comment: Yes, You can disable the option or uninstall the extension.